How to Retrieve Number of Connects and Bids Using Upwork Market Place Job Posting GraphQL API
I am using new upwork graphql api to fetch job search data
My current query looks like this with this api (https://api.upwork.com/graphql):
"query": "query marketplaceJobPostingsSearch($marketPlaceJobFilter: MarketplaceJobPostingsSearchFilter, $searchType: MarketplaceJobPostingSearchType, $sortAttributes: [MarketplaceJobPostingSearchSortAttribute]) { marketplaceJobPostingsSearch(marketPlaceJobFilter: $marketPlaceJobFilter, searchType: $searchType, sortAttributes: $sortAttributes) { totalCount edges { node { id title  amount {rawValue} experienceLevel totalApplicants createdDateTime description category duration hourlyBudgetMin {rawValue} hourlyBudgetMax {rawValue} weeklyBudget {rawValue} engagement client {companyName} applied } } pageInfo { hasNextPage endCursor } } }
I am getting response successfully but unable to get specific fields like number of connects, number of bids which are essential for my use case. I am following this documentation : https://www.upwork.com/developer/documentation/graphql/api/docs/index.html#definition-MarketplaceJobPostingSearchResult
This does not include any info of number of connects, total bids.
Unfortunately, the documentation does not include information about these fields.

Is there a workaround to fetch this data?
Am I missing something in the query or the documentation?

Any guidance would be appreciated!
